# (LibGDX) Changing Color of Actor

Tags: java, libgdx

So, I have a class that extends `Actor`, and I'm trying to change the alpha value of it; `objectPreview` is a type of that class:

```
@Override
public void display() {

    ...

    // remove previous object preview from stage
    objectPreview.remove();

    ... 

    // add a translucent preview of where the object will be added
    objectPreview.getColor().a = 0.5f;
    stage.addActor(objectPreview);

    ...

    stage.draw();
}
```

And here's my `draw` method of my custom `Actor`:

```
@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha) {
    batch.enableBlending();
    batch.draw(texture, pos.x, pos.y);
}
```

The `display` method is called every frame, and the `objectPreview` is an `Actor` that was added to `stage`.

However, modifying the alpha value of `objectPreview` does not work.

Otherwise, this works as intended, placing a preview of the `Actor` on the screen and clearing / redrawing it every frame.

I have also tried the `setColor()` method, and that does not work. Even if I change the r, g, b vaulues, nothing happens; the object is still the original `Actor's` texture.

Why isn't the `Color` of the actor changing?

Comment: What does the draw method of your custom actor look like?

Comment: Edited in the OP! @Tenfour04

Comment: Putting my kids to bed, will answer in a few minutes. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you subclass Actor, it is left up to you to apply its own color in the `draw` method. I am not sure why they didn't build this into the Actor class, except maybe that there are so many possible ways that color might be used, or because some Actors don't have any visuals associated with them, so applying the color would waste time.

First of all, note that the second argument passed into the draw method is `parentAlpha`, not `alpha` as you have labeled it. This is because the parent's alpha should be multiplied by the child's alpha for proper fade effects.

So your updated `draw` method should look like this:

```
@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    batch.enableBlending(); //You can probably remove this line*
    Color color = getColor(); //keep reference to avoid multiple method calls
    batch.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a * parentAlpha);
    batch.draw(texture, pos.x, pos.y);
}

/*    * It would only be useful if you have some custom Actors that disable blending. 
I don't think any of the built-in actors disable blending. Since many actors will 
require blending, it is usually best to leave it on even for fully opaque sprites, in 
order to avoid ending up with many draw calls. */
```

Also note that if you wanted to take advantage of Actor's already existing `scaleX` and `scaleY` fields, it would also be up to you to modify the `draw` method accordingly to use them.

Comment: That's it! Thank you, that makes total sense!